# Implement array and iterate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this Ruby code that I want to use:

```
if args[:remove_existing_trxs] == 'true'
    Acquirer.delete_all
    Company.delete_all
    Currency.delete_all
    AdminUser.delete_all
    BaseReseller.delete_all
    Terminal.delete_all
    Contract.delete_all
    Merchant.delete_all
    MerchantUser.delete_all
    PaymentTransaction.delete_all
  end
```

How can I define it as an array and iterate?

Comment: Wouldn't dependency_true on each model (with defined model association) be more appropriate on this scenario and use one delete_all to delete the dependencies?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails-4`, are you targeting both versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that?

```
[Model1, Model2].each do |model|
  model.public_send(:delete_all)
end
```

Or with using [`Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

```
[Model1, Model2].each(&:delete_all)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

```
  if args[:remove_existing_trxs] == 'true'
    [Acquirer, Company, Currency, AdminUser,
    BaseReseller, Terminal, Contract, Merchant,
    MerchantUser, PaymentTransaction].each(&:destroy_all)
  end
```